# Batch path substitution on variables

Tags: variables, batch-file, filepath, substitution

How can I do the same substitution as you can do on `%0` .. `%9`, (like `%~dp0`) but on a variable ?

example :

```
set MYVAR = %*
echo %~dp{%MYVAR%}  <--- how to do that ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

not-so-short answer: you can do it with a little trick:

```
set "myvar=C:\any folder\subfolder\my file.ext"
for %%i in ("%myvar%") do echo %%~dpi, %%~ni
```

`for` is used to convert a `%variable%` to a `%variable` (`%%variable` inside batchfiles)

Comment: You should maybe note that `set` can also be used in a `for do` loop.

Comment: more urgent to note, that `set MYVAR = %*` sets a variable `%MYVAR %` instead of `%MYVAR%` - to a value that starts with a space.
`